# Simple carousel prev/next jquery function - prev function not working

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have a problem in "PREV" jquery function in the following carousel, please help.

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div id="product-detail-image-wrapper">
        <div id="product-detail-image-inner-wrapper">
            <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/01.jpg" />
            <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/02.jpg" />
            <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/03.jpg" />
            <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/04.jpg" />
            <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/05.jpg" />
        </div>
        <img id="image-control-left" src="images/left-arrow.png" onclick="showPrev();" />
        <img id="image-control-right" src="images/right-arrow.png" onclick="showNext();" />                         
    </div>
</div>
```

The showNext() function is working perfect. But the showPrev() is not working.

At the beginning, only the first image will show, others will not show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide all the images except the first one...
    $('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
});

function showNext() {
    $('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
        .next('img').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper');                     
    
}

function showPrev() {
    $('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
         .last('img').fadeIn()
         .end().prependTo('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper');                       
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what the error in showPrev() function? I tried so many times, but doesn't work. Much appreciated.

In showNext() function, when clicking "next" button, image "01" will fade out and image "02" will fade in, and then image "01" will go to the end of the list like this :

```
<div id="product-detail-image-inner-wrapper">
    <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/02.jpg" />
    <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/03.jpg" />
    <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/04.jpg" />
    <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/05.jpg" />
    <img class="product-detail-image" src="images/01.jpg" />
</div>
```

The last 4 lines above will be set to "display:none;".
I am expecting the same behavior in the reverse pattern in showPrev() function.

Comment: may be: .prev('img')....

Comment: Thanks gaetanoM. But this is not working.

Comment: why do you not use crousel component?

Comment: Thanks Moti. But I avoid extra JS libraries such as Bootstrap. I only use just one JS library, that is JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had turn on your DevTols you would see that right image was not selected nor moved properly to first place.

When moving backwards you need to: fade out first image, find last one, fade it in and move to first position.

```
function showPrev() {
  $('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
    .nextAll('img:last-of-type').fadeIn().end();
  $("#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper :last-child").prependTo('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper');
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide all the images except the first one...
  $('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
});

function showNext() {
  $('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
    .next('img').fadeIn()
    .end().appendTo('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper');

}

function showPrev() {
  $('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
    .nextAll('img:last-of-type').fadeIn().end();
  $("#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper :last-child").prependTo('#product-detail-image-inner-wrapper');
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel">
  <div id="product-detail-image-wrapper">
    <div id="product-detail-image-inner-wrapper">
      <img class="product-detail-image" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.dAEeeFKKWyKvfi09BT_b7QHaFj%26pid%3DApi&f=1" title="1" />
      <img class="product-detail-image" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.hUrigs4oGP1BPza_niQmnQHaFh%26pid%3DApi&f=1" title="2" />
      <img class="product-detail-image" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.w4J0Joa9SQJjntfW3Bl2kgHaD5%26pid%3DApi&f=1" title="3" />
      <img class="product-detail-image" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.QEM5dAvEzjYwaND5AmgsQgHaEM%26pid%3DApi&f=1" title="4" />
      <img class="product-detail-image" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.loIp0wgsX2e_eppiqs-pvgHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1" title="5" />
    </div>
    <button id="image-control-left" onclick="showPrev();">-</button>
    <button id="image-control-right" onclick="showNext();">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ikiK. Really appreciated. It works. Thanks again.

Comment: @Isaac Np, please consider marking answer as accepted on ✔︎  button,  so it marks question as solved for others. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

here is the standart code for crousel with your images.

```html
  <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/01.jpg" alt="slide 1">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/02.jpg" alt="slide 2">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/03.jpg" alt="slide 3">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/04.jpg" alt="slide 4">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/05.jpg" alt="slide 5">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      </html>
```

Comment: Who said anything about bootstrap?

Comment: "Simple carousel prev/next jquery function - prev function not working".
this is simpliest carousel.

Comment: Correct. I avoid loading big libraries, otherwise there are thousands of carousel examples in the net, but they use huge libraries, therefore I thought of writing a simple carousel by myself. Thanks to Moti for suggesting Bootstrap, but I prefer simpler one without the use of a JS library. Thanks ikiK for your simple solution - really appreciated.